# item click for recycler view

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement on item click for different items that i pop up in `RecyclerView`. I achieved that in `listView` but `RecyclerView` seem to be difficult. I have look at similar questions but couldn't get a solution.

if the user clicks on One, I want it to do something, also for two, and three. How do i get achieve this?

**Here are my codes**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    public static MainFragment newInstance() {
        return new MainFragment();
    }

    private static final String[] MOVIES = new String[]{ "One", "Two", "Three" };

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ExampleAdapter mAdapter;
    private List<ExampleModel> mModels;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tms, container, false);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        mModels = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String movie : MOVIES) {
            mModels.add(new ExampleModel(movie));
        }

        mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(getActivity(), mModels);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_two, menu);

        final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
        final List<ExampleModel> filteredModelList = filter(mModels, query);
        mAdapter.animateTo(filteredModelList);
        mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    private List<ExampleModel> filter(List<ExampleModel> models, String query) {
        query = query.toLowerCase();

        final List<ExampleModel> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ExampleModel model : models) {
            final String text = model.getText().toLowerCase();
            if (text.contains(query)) {
                filteredModelList.add(model);
            }
        }
        return filteredModelList;
    }
}
```

The ViewHolder

```
public class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private final TextView tvText;

    public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvText);
    }

    public void bind(ExampleModel model) {
        tvText.setText(model.getText());  
    }
}
```

Here is the Adapter that extends the RecyclerView-

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleViewHolder> {

    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private final List<ExampleModel> mModels;

    public ExampleAdapter(Context context, List<ExampleModel> models) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mModels = new ArrayList<>(models);
    }

    @Override
    public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final View itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.it_file, parent, false);
        return new ExampleViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final ExampleModel model = mModels.get(position);
        holder.bind(model);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mModels.size();
    }

    public void animateTo(List<ExampleModel> models) {
        applyAndAnimateRemovals(models);
        applyAndAnimateAdditions(models);
        applyAndAnimateMovedItems(models);
    }

    private void applyAndAnimateRemovals(List<ExampleModel> newModels) {
        for (int i = mModels.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            final ExampleModel model = mModels.get(i);
            if (!newModels.contains(model)) {
                removeItem(i);
            }
        }
    }

    private void applyAndAnimateAdditions(List<ExampleModel> newModels) {
        for (int i = 0, count = newModels.size(); i < count; i++) {
            final ExampleModel model = newModels.get(i);
            if (!mModels.contains(model)) {
                addItem(i, model);
            }
        }
    }

    private void applyAndAnimateMovedItems(List<ExampleModel> newModels) {
        for (int toPosition = newModels.size() - 1; toPosition >= 0; toPosition--) {
            final ExampleModel model = newModels.get(toPosition);
            final int fromPosition = mModels.indexOf(model);
            if (fromPosition >= 0 && fromPosition != toPosition) {
                moveItem(fromPosition, toPosition);
            }
        }
    }

    public ExampleModel removeItem(int position) {
        final ExampleModel model = mModels.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        return model;
    }

    public void addItem(int position, ExampleModel model) {
        mModels.add(position, model);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }

    public void moveItem(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        final ExampleModel model = mModels.remove(fromPosition);
        mModels.add(toPosition, model);
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    }
}
```

if the user clicks on One, I want it to do something,also for two and three. How do i get achieve this?

Comment: refer androidhive or you can follow Android Nerd answer.. this is the best solution for your question.

Answer (score 1):

**MainActivity.java**

```
public interface ClickListener {
    void onClick(View view, int position);
    void onLongClick(View view, int position);
}

public static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private MainActivity.ClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final MainActivity.ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
}
```

And

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new  RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view, int position) {
        Movie movie = movieList.get(position);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), movie.getTitle() + " is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
    }
}));
```

You have to make an interface and have you use `GestureDetector` to detect the view has been clicked!

Please note that its just an example to give hints to you

Just try to know yourself what is happening in this code and what you need is what you want. You can edit and reuse this example for you.

Comment: If you find this helpful please accept this answer to help others

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the `onClickListener` to `itemView`, like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final ExampleModel model = mModels.get(position);
    holder.bind(model);
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener( ... {

        if(position == 1){
            ...
        }else{
            ...
        }

    });
}
```

or do it in `ExampleViewHolder.bind()`, then you can pass an argument to it like `position`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `setOnClickListener` in the `onBindViewHolder` of your Adapter and use your `model` variable there