# RecyclerView in Fragment initialize

Tags: java, android

I'm new with recyclerview, using it with cardview, can somebody tell me how to initialize it?

I see I have to somehow put it in onCreateView, not in ViewCreated, my code:

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_genres, container, false);
```

and code of recycler what I was using on Activity but now I want to trigger it in fragments

```
  recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

The trace of data:

```
JSON>get>DataModel>Adapter>Recycler>CardView
```

When I have it in onCreatedView, LogCat says:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just like this

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                     @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_genres, container, false);
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
return v;
```

Comment: Yes but in 7 minutes, time limit

Comment: I accepted answer, have you an idea how to setAdapter for this?
  adapter = new CardAdapter(listSuperSongs, getActivity());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
Tried in this way but... list is empty, so cannot load it. It's coming from internet json, when user made click action on different list element.

Comment: When are you getting the listSuperSongs? You can load the adapter with an empty arraylist and update the listSuperSongs when you get the data. Just call adapter.notifydatasetchanged(); after inserting.

Comment: private List<DataModel> listSuperSongs;    list is not empty, it's just null. What should I do? Create list object with some " " values?

Comment: List<DataModel> listSuperSongs = new ArrayList<>();

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_genres, container, false);
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recyclerView); recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true); layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()); recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    return v;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I successfully integrated Recyclerview in a fragment called MainFragment 
[item click for recycler view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38172875/item-click-for-recycler-view)
the initialization of the fragment in the main activity is not there. use this to reference the fragment

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super. onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R . layout . activity_main);
if(savedInstanceState == null ) {
getSupportFragmentManager() . beginTransaction()
.replace(R . id . container, MainFragment . newInstance())
.commit();
```