# Images are not showing after implementing Pagination in my RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, pagination, infinite-scroll, endlessscroll

I have implemented `Pagination` in my `RecyclerView` but after implementing pagination the images are not showing up

Ok I have implemented this pagination [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26561717/12438238)

Ok because the answer above is for `LinearLayoutManager` and I'm using `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` I have done some modifications in the `addOnScrollListener`

> I have only included the necessary code of `Home_Fragment.java` so it doesn't get confusing
> and long but if you want more references to the code please tell me I
> will update the question

**Home_Fragment.java**

```
    private int previousTotal = 0;
    private final int visibleThreshold = 5;
    private RecyclerView postRecyclerView;
    private boolean loading = true;
    private int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;

 @SuppressLint("SourceLockedOrientationActivity")
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

 StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        postRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(
                staggeredGridLayoutManager
        );


        postRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

                visibleItemCount = staggeredGridLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                totalItemCount = staggeredGridLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                int[] firstVisibleItems = null;
                firstVisibleItems = staggeredGridLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPositions(firstVisibleItems);
                if (loading) {
                    if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                        loading = false;
                        previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                    }
                }

                if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)
                        <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                    getData();

                    loading = true;
                }
            }
        });

return view;
    }

private void getData() {
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    shimmerFrameLayout.stopShimmer();
                    shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    postRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mUploads.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Upload upload = dataSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                        assert upload != null;
                        upload.setmKey(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                        mUploads.add(upload);


                    }

                }
                postsAdapter.setUploads(mUploads);

                //notify the adapter
                postsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

**PostAdapter_Home.java**

```
public class PostAdapter_Home extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter_Home.PostViewHolder> {
    public static List<Upload> mUploads;
    public Context mcontext;

    public PostAdapter_Home(Context context, List<Upload> uploads) {
        mUploads = uploads;
        mcontext = context;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        view = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext).inflate(R.layout.ex_home, parent, false);
        return new PostViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Shimmer shimmer = new Shimmer.ColorHighlightBuilder()
                .setBaseColor(Color.parseColor("#F3F3F3"))
                .setBaseAlpha(1)
                .setHighlightColor(Color.parseColor("#E7E7E7"))
                .setHighlightAlpha(1)
                .setDropoff(50)
                .build();
        ShimmerDrawable shimmerDrawable = new ShimmerDrawable();
        shimmerDrawable.setShimmer(shimmer);
        Upload uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
        Glide.with(mcontext)
                .load(uploadCurrent.getmImageUrl())
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
                .placeholder(shimmerDrawable)
                .centerCrop()
                .fitCenter()
                .into(holder.imageView);

//        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(view -> changeScaleType(holder, position));

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUploads.size();
    }

    public void setUploads(List<Upload> uploads){
        mUploads=uploads;
    }
    public static class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final ShapeableImageView imageView;

        public PostViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagePostHome);

        }


    }
}
```

**Update** // Added Upload.java file as requested

**Upload.java**

```
package com.example.myappnotfinal.AdaptersAndMore;

import com.google.firebase.database.Exclude;

public class Upload {
    private String mImageUrl;
    private String mKey;
    private String mUserName;
    private String mComment;

    public Upload() {

    }

    public Upload(String imageUrl) {
        mImageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getmUserName() {
        return mUserName;
    }

    public void setmUserName(String mUserName) {
        this.mUserName = mUserName;
    }

    public String getmComment() {
        return mComment;
    }

    public void setmComment(String mComment) {
        this.mComment = mComment;
    }

    public String getmImageUrl() {
        return mImageUrl;
    }

    public void setmImageUrl(String mImageUrl) {
        this.mImageUrl = mImageUrl;
    }

    @Exclude
    public String getmKey() {
        return mKey;
    }

    @Exclude
    public void setmKey(String Key) {
        this.mKey = Key;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Home Fragment Code wise RecyclerView did not initialize. At first, initialize RecyclerView. [Image Loder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32706246/recyclerview-adapter-and-glide-same-image-every-4-5-rows) [RecyclerView initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38174829/recyclerview-in-fragment-initialize)

Comment: i have initialized the recycler view i just didn't induce that code

Comment: your image loader code is ok. and can you give me an image URL. and also you can try Picasso: [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: images are perfectly showing when i didn't include the pagination

Comment: ok please check the updated question

Comment: why do you add scroll listener in onCreateView? you should do it separately IMO.

Comment: I have seen many answers that implemented the same way so I did so

Comment: I would think about using a modern architecture approach and usage of Android Jetpack Architecture Components. The pagination approach you used is from 2014 ;)
Using MVVM architecture will make your code lot of more flexible. See:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-overview

Comment: but it is for kotlin

Comment: Sure, but it's worth it switching over to Kotlin. Sooner or later Java stuff becomes more and more irrelevant in the Android world and you will stuck on such old and complex solutions.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion actually I'm thinking to migrate my project to Kotlin but I'm pretty new and I don't know how the Kotlin community support is on SO

Comment: It's at least as good as for java IMHO and growing, cause more and more devs are switching. Once you got a bit familiar with it you'll love it i promise and you will think java is a language from the last century

Comment: Thank you so much , actually I'm making a social media kind of app , and I don't know java completely I'm just learning the stuff that I required for this particular app but atleast I'm familiar with java from quite a long time , but with Kotlin I'm not familiar that much I have stated learning the basics of Kotlin , should I switch from java to Kotlin now ,is it good for my app and for me

Comment: I'm really confused about the switching , should I do it right now, or sometime latter

Comment: hey there i have switched from java to kotlin and trying to add the paging dependency but there are some issues, can u help me